# How to remove a list (ul) using mootools

Tags: mootools

Im using mootoolsv1.3.2. Using mootools how to remove the Ul from the below code.
My present code:

```
<ul class="clean menu" id="topics">
    <li class="drop png">
        <a cat="ntech" class="sec_accnt" href="javascript:void(0);" name="&amp;lid=choose_category_billing" rel="1" style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 13px -164px">Billing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="drop png">
        <div class="add">
            <span href="#" id="tv" style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 13px 9px">TV</span>
        </div>
        <ul class="clean menu sub">
            <li>
                <a cat="tech" class="sec_tv" href="javascript:void(0);" name="&amp;lid=choose_category_tv_fios" rel="1">FiOS TV</a>
            </li>
            <li class="last" style="margin-bottom:6px;">
                <a cat="tech" class="sec_tv_1" href="javascript:void(0);" name="&amp;lid=choose_category_tv_direct" rel="1">DIRECTV</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Should look like this:

```
<ul class="clean menu" id="topics">
    <li class="drop png">
        <a cat="ntech" class="sec_accnt" href="javascript:void(0);" name="&amp;lid=choose_category_billing" rel="1" style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 13px -164px">Billing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="drop png">
        <a cat="ntech" class="sec_tv_fios" href="javascript:void(0);" name="&amp;lid=choose_category_tv" rel="1" style="BACKGROUND-POSITION: 13px -164px">TV</a>
    </li>   
</ul>
```

The change should be based on the value of a flag variable.

```
If flag=0{
   code remains same
}else{
   code changes as mentioned.
}
```

Someone please help with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Safe way which makes sure the sub menu is a child of 'topics'

```
$('topics').getElements('ul.sub').destroy();
```

destroy() will make sure that the DOM elements will be GC:ed